# Retrieving value from jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

Trying to retrieve a 422 error response value from an ajax call but cant work out the syntax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    statusCode: {
        // success
        200: function() {
        },
        // bad request
        400: function() {},
        // not acceptable
        406: function() {},
        // request timeout
        408: function() {},
        // unprecessable
        422: function(responseJSON) {
            console.log(responseJSON.detail.hint);
            
        }
    }
});
```

This is what I get in the console. I am trying to get the values for the responseJSON for  'message' and 'hint' but not sure what the syntax should be?

[image]

Using this

```
responseJSON.detail.hint
```

which gives me

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hint')

This is Jquery ajax, question was closed due to duplication but used different technology.

Comment: `fetch().then(r => switch(r.status){ case 200: ...; })`

Comment: did you debug what is in the response? `console.log(responseJSON)`

Comment: it gave me this

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'hint')